# Call SQL function with C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I write this function in SQL:

```
   ALTER FUNCTION Fn_CheckBill
(
@image AS image,
@number AS nvarchar(50),
@date AS nchar(10)
)
RETURNS bit
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @flag bit;
IF EXISTS ( SELECT * 
            FROM tblBill 
            WHERE ((cast([Image] as varbinary(max)) = cast(@image as varbinary(max))) AND (Number = @number) AND ([Date] = @date)) )
            BEGIN
                SET @flag = 0
            END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @flag = 1
    END

RETURN @flag
END
```

And write this code in my C# source code:

```
int flag;
    try
    {
        objCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT Fn_CheckBill(@image,@date,@number) AS int");
        objCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("image", image);
        objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("number", number);
        objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("date", _Date);

        using (objConnection = new SqlConnection(connenctString))
        {

            objConnection.Open();
            objCommand.Connection = objConnection;
            flag = int.Parse(objCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
        }

        if (flag == 1)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
```

But It throw this exception when executed: 
'Fn_CheckBill' is not a recognized function name.

Please help me to solve this problem :(

Comment: Are you sure you connected the right database in your connection string?

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: Scalar functions are not a great choice from a performance perspective. You could certainly streamline this one into a single query instead of the if else logic here. Far worse however is the usage of the image datatype. That datatype has been deprecated for a decade and you should avoid using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to supply the schema in any SQL function call

```
objCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT dbo.Fn_CheckBill(@image,@date,@number) AS int");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would consider rewriting this as an inline table valued function. Something like this:

```
create FUNCTION Fn_CheckBill
(
    @image AS varbinary(max),
    @number AS nvarchar(50),
    @date AS nchar(10)
)
RETURNS table
AS
RETURN
    SELECT CAST(count(*) as bit) as RowFound
    FROM tblBill 
    WHERE [Image] = @image
        AND Number = @number
        AND [Date] = @date
```